# Correctly specifying non-fractional CGFloat values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When setting whole `CGFloat` values (and thus by implication `float` and `double` values) is it best practice to include the decimal point or does it not matter? For example:

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 200);         // Approach 1
CGRect rect2 = CGRectMake(0.0, 10.0, 100.0, 200.0); // Approach 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will do an implicit conversion to float, so either method should result in the same float value.

However, your Approach 2 is actually specifying a value of type double, which is then converted to float.  To explicitly specify a float you need to add an `f` suffix  ie `200.0f`

Personally I always specify values like this as `xxx.0f` just to keep reminding me that they are floats, and screw the extra work the compiler has to do to interpret my code - it's there to do my bidding, not the other way around.

Of course I would also do:

```
static const float left = 0.0f;
static const float top = 10.0f;
static const float width = 100.0f;
static const float height = 200.0f;

CGRect rect3 = CGRectMake(left, top, width, height);
```

Comment: Little known fact: you don't need the last 0. `200.f` works fine too.

Comment: @KurtRevis Yeah I know .. but I am being anal about it :D  Besides when specifying constants like this I do tend end up tweaking them by fractional amounts, so I keep the decimal hanging around more by habit than anything..

Answer (score 2):

Commonly they're the same, as the implicit cast can't cause a loss of precision with common values like 10, 20, etc...
But just in the rare case that the integer goes in overflow, you'd better use a float.
For example:

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, INT_MAX+1);
```

Vs:

```
CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, (float)INT_MAX+1);
```

These two expressions give total different values.
At your place I would use just integers, and turn to a float only when I need to have the decimal precision, or when I may risk to have an integer overflow.